# django 2, list passed to template with different nested objects, how to access each object?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm passing a list to the template that looks like this with real data

```
list = [[<Conversation: Conversation object(1)>, datetime.datetime,
<QuerySet [{'username: 'admin'}]>]]
```

I want to loop through this in the template and each loop has access to all three items.  I'm not sure the ideal way to do this or if I should format my list differently or pull the data in the views first, serialize it and loop through the raw data in the template.

```
{% for l in list %}
   // Here I should have access to the three objects
   {{ l.0.id }}  //Should print the id of the conversation object
   {{ l.1 }}  // Should print off the datetime stamp
   {{ l.2.username }} // Should print off admin
{% endfor %}
```

Any help with be great.

Comment: If you feel like my answer is not adequate, I'm certainly open to improving it with your suggestions if you would like it to function differently

Comment: Your answer was correct and I was able to do what I needed to to.  I did hit another problem related to the M2M field in the Conversation object so I'm working on manipulating your solution to resolve that problem.  Apparently Django doesn't pull all of the values in a M2M, just the first one it comes across.

Comment: If you post another question I would be glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass it a `dict` or `list` of `dict`

For example:

```
list = [{"conversation":ConversationObject, "date":datetime.datetime, "user":UserObject}]
```

Then in your template, can do something like:

```
{% for item in list%}
    item.conversation.id
    item.date
    item.user
{%endfor%}
```